# Devexpress chart control, default checked out series

Tags: c#, charts, devexpress

I have many series in my chart control. When the program is first loaded, I can see them all at once, when I click on the checkboxes in Legend, they disappear. However, I want all of them to be unchecked when first opened (not visible), but let the user open what they want to see.

[image]

If I set visible to false from the settings (even if "Show in Legend" is on). The serial disappears from everywhere and the user cannot open it again.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution to set the `CheckedInLegend` property to false (for all series).

For example:

```
<dxc:SplineSeries2D DisplayName="Room Temp" ArgumentScaleType="DateTime" ArgumentDataMember="date_time" ValueDataMember="room_temp"  CheckedInLegend="False"  FilterString=""   />
```